# Excel highlight cell (text) that equals one of multiple other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2019

I want to format cells `$C$2:$C$32` if their value (text) is equal to not one other specific cell but one out of multiple cells, let's say `$C$35:$C$42`.
Additionally blank cells should remain untouched.

How do I do that? Formatting cells based on another cell is easy, but if multiple cells are involved it gets kind of tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a countif formula within your conditional format rule. Here I selected cells C2:C13, then went to conditional formatting.

```
Formula: =COUNTIF($C$17:$C$23,C2)>0
```

[image]

Format how you wish, and here's output after pressing OK. Blank cells are ignored.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select Range **$C$2:$C$32**- go to **Home**- **Conditional Formatting**- **New Rule...** - **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**- enter the formula and set the cell Format:

```
=MATCH(C2,$C$35:$C$42,0)<>0
```

[image]